# Trying to implement Django Admin model validation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am a beginner and trying to implement bid system in Django. I want it to work on both Django admin page and and template, therefore I created modelform and modeladmin in Admins.py.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass



class category(models.Model):
    category =  models.CharField(max_length=50, default='SOME STRING')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category}"


class bid(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey('listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}, {self.listing} {self.bid}"

class listing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Title}"
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, listing, category, bid
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django import forms
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(listing)
admin.site.register(category)

class bidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=bid
        fields = ['user', 'listing', 'bid']
    def clean(self):
        start_price = self.cleaned_data.get('listing.Price')
        userbid = self.cleaned_data.get('bid')
        if userbid <= start_price:
            raise ValidationError('Please place a bid higher than starting price')
        return self.cleaned_data

class bidAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = bidForm
    list_display = ('user', 'listing', 'bid')
admin.site.register(bid, bidAdmin)
```

It returns the following error:
'<=' not supported between instances of 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'.
Also I want to compare instances of previous and current bid on a listing to place a new bid, also modify any of previously placed bids even if it's lower than highest bid. but I have no idea how to code that. Please, help me...